# Generalize SQL query to include data for all Users

Tags: sql, sql-server, data.stackexchange.com

[This](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag) popular `data.stackexchange.com` query allows me to query all tags of a user combined with their upvotes.

E.g. for user `22656` the follwing is outputed:

```
TagName, Upvotes
c#, 147346
java, 84373
.net, 49952
```

I would like to extract this information for all (or a large subset of) users. Can somebody help me generalize this query?

Example output could be:

```
user1, {"tagA": 6, "tagB": 4, ...}
user2, {"tagX": 7, "tagY": 3, ...}
...
userN, {"tagB": 3, "tagA": 1, ...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Posts.OwnerUserId,
       TagName,
       COUNT(*) AS UpVotes 
FROM Tags
    INNER JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.id
    INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.ParentId = PostTags.PostId
    INNER JOIN Votes ON Votes.PostId = Posts.Id and VoteTypeId = 2
GROUP BY Posts.OwnerUserId, TagName 
ORDER BY UpVotes DESC
```